# How to let my component rerender after ajax call?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a reactjsapp and this is part of my main component:

```
render() {
    console.log('main=this.props.data', this.props.data);
    console.log('main=this.props.userData', this.props.userData);
    return (
        <section className="app container">

            <PacksContainer packsData={this.props.userData} ></PacksContainer>

            <div className="row">
                <section className="container">
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
}



const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    return {
        data: store.datas,
        userData: store.apiData
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainLayout);
```

The data from an ajax call gets injected into the props, the state logger says the state has been successfully populated from the async response. However the render() does not fire again and the props.data does not get updated, stays undefined? How can I rerender the component?

Comment: As long as you state doesn't change, rerender is not triggered. Only when there is a difference between the present and the current state, re-render is triggered. Its difficult to  guess something form this code. you should provide code for the relevant reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using react-redux. you have to update state from reducer.

### dispatch action

```
let action = {type: 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE', payload: userData}

store.dispatch(action)
```

### reducer take state, action then return new state

from your app index where you created redux "store"

```
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, ...);
```

your store needs a reducer which is a function that take (state, action) and return nextState

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if(action.type === 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE') {
    // update new state
    return Object.assign({}, ...state, {userData: action.payload})
  }
  //..
}
```

your connected Component will update when state changed

```
// this will be called when you dispatch any action and the component will update with new props
const mapStateToProps = function (state) { // new state returned from reducer
    return {
        data: state.datas,
        userData: state.apiData
    };
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do.  If I put a console.log(action) inside my reducer, I see it output several steps in the console.  But for some reason, it just doesn't update my connected component after the data is loaded from an ajax call.

Comment: @pixelwiz I am facing the same issue. Do you find a solution?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash I'm pretty sure I got it to work in the project I was playing with at the time.  I can't remember exactly how, but you can check it out here: https://github.com/pixelwiz/reactjs-flickr-slider-search/tree/master/src

Comment: @pixelwiz I got it working and surprisingly I forgot what exactly was the issue. Thanks for the response :)